Averaging a nowhere continuous function defined on the rationals?
Suppose, we define function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$, where:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in\left\{\frac{2p+1}{2q}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z},q\neq0\right\}\\
0 & x\not\in\left\{\frac{2p+1}{2q}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z},q\neq0\right\}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Question: How would we get a unique, satisfying average of $f$?
Note, the expected value of non-equivelant sequences of bounded functions (with bounded domains) that converge to $f$, have different values depending the sequence of functions chosen.
Proof: Suppose,
$$(A_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}=(\left\{c/r!:c\in\mathbb{Z},-r\cdot r!\le c \le r\cdot r!\right\})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$$
and
$$(A_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}=(\left\{c/d:c\in\mathbb{Z},d\in\mathbb{N},d\le j,-dj\le c\le dj\right\})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$$
where for $f_r^{\star}:A_r^{\star}\to\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:fr}
f_r^{\star}(x)=f(x) \text{ for all $x\in A_r^{\star}$}
\end{equation}
and for $f_j^{\star\star}:A_j^{\star\star}\to\mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:fj}
f_j^{\star\star}(x)=f(x) \text{ for all $x\in A_j^{\star\star}$}
\end{equation}
The set-theoretic limit of $(A_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(A_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is $A=\mathbb{Q}$: i.e.,
\begin{gather*}
 \limsup_{r\to\infty}A_r^{\star}=\bigcap_{r\ge 1}\bigcup_{q\ge r}A_q^{\star}\\
 \liminf_{r\to\infty}A_r^{\star}=\bigcup_{r\ge 1}\bigcap_{q\ge r}A_q^{\star}
 \end{gather*}
where:
$$\limsup_{r\to\infty}A_r^{\star}=\liminf_{r\to\infty}A_r^{\star}=A=\mathbb{Q}$$
Now, suppose we want to average $f_r^{\star}$ and $f_j^{\star\star}$ which we denote $\mathbb{E}[f_r^{\star}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[f_j^{\star\star}]$. Note, this is the same as computing the following (i.e., the cardinality is $|\cdot|$ and the absolute value is $||\cdot||$):
\begin{equation}\label{avg:fr}
\forall(\epsilon>0)\exists(N\in\mathbb{N})\forall(r\in\mathbb{N})\left(r\ge N \Rightarrow \left|\left|\frac{1}{|A_r^{\star}|}\int_{A_r^{\star}}f(x) \, -\mathbb{E}[f_r^{\star}]\right|\right|<\epsilon\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{avg:fj}
\forall(\epsilon>0)\exists(N\in\mathbb{N})\forall(j\in\mathbb{N})\left(j\ge N \Rightarrow \left|\left|\frac{1}{|A_j^{\star\star}|}\int_{A_j^{\star\star}}f(x) \, -\mathbb{E}[f_j^{\star\star}]\right|\right|<\epsilon\right)
\end{equation}
See section 1.3.1 of this paper for proof that $\mathbb{E}[f_r^{\star}]=1$ and $\mathbb{E}[f_j^{\star\star}]=1/3$
Question: Which sequence of bounded functions (with bounded domains) should be chosen, so its' expected value is an unique, satisfying average of $f$?
